# Validating decomposition of Synthetic Tensor generated from Unevenly Sampled Tensor

Tags: validation, interpolation, matrix-decomposition, synthetic-data, tensor

I have a 3-way tensor generated from 7 experiments, with each experiment being matricized and becoming a frontal slice of the tensor (thus mode-3 is of length 7). The data is generated from fluorescence spectroscopy with varying excitation frequency being represented in mode-3.

However, the distances between the frontal slices of the tensor/excitation frequencies are not evenly sampled (illustration attempted below) in wavelength. Sometimes there's a 50 nanometer jump from slice to slice, and sometimes it's 15 nanometers. Also, the slices become increasingly sparse (most rows become zero) as you increase the excitation. The experiments cannot be repeated, and this is the data I have to work with.

[image]

When I apply a tensor decomposition using CP/PARAFAC or any of its variants, I find far fewer components than our biochemist colleagues hypothesize (Side note: this is exploratory work, no ground truth currently exists). If I increase the number of components in the decomposition, there is a strong tendency to over-fit the data based on the [Corcondia](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cem.801/abstract) metric.

I had an idea to interpolate using the scattered data points along mode-3 (along the red line) for each of the entries in the matrix slices and to resample evenly. This has the effect of making my tensor more dense as the biggest jumps are in between the dense slices, and the decomposition yields a few more components with both reasonable core consistencies (quantitative) and biochemical interpretations (qualitative).

Question: I cannot think of a way to mathematically validate/invalidate my intuition of making the tensor more dense. Is there some glaring error I'm not seeing? Is there a more mathematically correct way of generating synthetic data based on sparse samples of real data? The data is going to have significantly different properties based on the interpolation used and I can't think of a reason to pick one over the other.

Comment: Inverse problem treatment lends itself to this problem type. Example solution [Pixon method](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9901063). Noise characteristics of data must be known and local adaptive smoothing applied to create model that best explains data. One then has smooth model within statistically acceptable thresholds as established by local noise and sparse data.

Comment: @Carl Thanks for responding! Sadly, noise characteristics of this data are unknown.

Comment: Gaussian noise is a common assumption for photon flux. Maybe get a physics consult.